# Restart Firefox with a cronjob

Tags: command-line, firefox

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 system that just runs Firefox all day. Now I want to restart Firefox automatically once a day, so I created the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
killall firefox
sleep 5
killall -9 firefox
sleep 2
/usr/bin/firefox -URL <...>
```

and set up da cronjob to call the script.
But it doesn't work, I get:

```
Error: no display specified
```

When I insert

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

I get

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a command through `xserver` of another user need to export two variables:
`XAUTHORITY` and `DISPLAY`.

First of all, is what `DISPLAY` is connected to the user by typing:

```
w
```

assuming that the user "username" uses the display "1", and that the script should be run at 23:30, upgrade your crontab, as follows:

```
30 23 *** export XAUTHORITY=/home/username/.Xauthority && export DISPLAY=:1 && /path/to/script 2> /tmp/error_cron.log
```

the last part of the line is to save any errors in `/tmp/error_cron.log`

Comment: Thanks! Actually, it's the same user, but I used the wrong display, it's 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

First be sure to edit the crontab with `crontab -e` and not one of the files under /etc (like `/etc/cron.hourly`).

Then you need to declare the **DISPLAY** variable in the cronjob itself:

```
DISPLAY=:0 /path/to/your/script
```

Comment: That didn't change anything. Still `Error: cannot open display: :0`.